# Disable cookies for specific sites in Firefox

Tags: privacy, firefox-for-android, cookies

Firefox on my PC allows me top disable cookies for specific sites by clicking on the website's icon. When cookies are disabled generally, I can enable them the same way in the menu behind the icon. Firefox on Android doesn't show this menu when I click on the icon. How can I disable/enable cookies for a specific site on Firefox for Android?

Comment: Do you've root access? Firefox for Android doesn't have in-built permissions manager interface neither it gives per-site option to change some settings. However, it does have the `permissions.sqlite` which holds permissions related to cookies. I guess you would need to manually edit that file to get the job done.

Comment: Yes I have root access. But does Firefox need additional permissions to modify its own cookies? It somehow must be able to access them, otherwise, I couldn't delete all cookies.

Answer (score 1):

With Firefox 57 support for extensions not using the WebExtensions API was dropped. Before that, you could whitelist specific sites using the [Cookie Whitelist for Fennec](https://addons.mozilla.org/android/addon/cookie-whitelist-for-fennec/) addon. The WebExtension API currently doesn’t offer a way for an extension to modify cookie permissions. Adding an API for that is discussed in Mozilla [bug 1291841](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1291841).

This leaves you with the following options:

- Try to find an older version of Firefox for Android and use the old addon (not recommended due to missing security updates and because you could find an APK containing malware)
- Wait for the API to be added
- Try to modify permissions.sqlite manually as suggested by Firelord in the comments
- Use another browser for sites needing cookies. I use [Firefox Focus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.focus) when I encounter a site needing session cookies. For sites needing permanent cookies to stay logged in you would need another browser.